# overlapping clickable elements on the iframe and the document

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser, onclick

I have an html page that embeds an invisible iframe. I have to detect overlapping clickable elements on the document and the iframe. For this purpose i have to collect coordinates of the click by the user(either on the iframe or on the document itself) and then return corresponding elements that are there on this location on the iframe and the document, and then check whether they are clickable or not.

Here i am able to collect coordinates of user click on the document and the corresponding element. But i am not able to find coordinates of user click on the iframe (i dont want to use div).

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: if the iframe is Invisible i.e its display is set to none, how it is overlapping with other elements

Comment: @Rex display is not set to none, opacity is set to 0.

Comment: @RoyMJ i am able to detect coordinates of the user click on document, but i am not able to collect coordinates of clicks done on the iframe by user.